# Erro Could not find crash.jar in Android studio

Tags: android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I'm having trouble finding no solution.
Please help if someone knows

Unexpected error occurred
Description in the picture below

Could not find crash.jar (com.android.tools.analytics-library:crash:26.2.1).
Searched in the following locations:
    https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/analytics-library/crash/26.2.1/crash-26.2.1.jar

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Llwbi.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5rgl.png)

Answer (score 1):

Delete all file ( .androidstudio  .gradle) from user folder and open again android studio.
(sure when delete files android studio colsed.)

Answer (score 0):

Deleting ~/.gradle ( in mac os ) should be enough. ( and make sure android studio is fully closed! )

[image]

For windows it's in C:/Users/YourUserName/

For me this error happened because network issue during downloading gradle stuff.. so after removing that directory everything works fine now.